# Swift -- "alias" an instance of an object

Tags: swift, reference, alias

Working on a simple card game to learn Swift and IOS programming. For this function, the following code will work:

```
func dealCards() {

    for _ in 0...9 {

        player1.cardDealt(deck.getNextCard())
        player2.cardDealt(deck.getNextCard())    
    }
}
```

However, I would like to rotate the dealer.  I know that I could duplicate the for loop within if/else blocks, but I would rather do something like this:

```
func dealCards() {

    // Dealer is considered position 2
    if player1.isDealer() {
        let pos1 = player2
        let pos2 = player1
    }
    else {
        let pos1 = player1
        let pos2 = player2
    }
    for _ in 0...9 {
        pos1.cardDealt(deck.getNextCard())
        pos2.cardDealt(deck.getNextCard())
    }
}
```

I'm sure it's simple, but I can't seem to figure out how to alias my player objects to use them in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code seems to be that you are defining `pos1` and `pos2` inside each `if` statement, and thus these values cannot be accessed from outside these statements. You need to first define them outside the statements and then set their values inside. You could even initially define them as `player1` and `player2` respectively, and swap their values `if player1.isDealer()`.

This is how it would look in the end:

```
func dealCards() {
    let pos1 = player1
    let pos2 = player2

    // Dealer is considered position 2
    if player1.isDealer() {
        pos1 = player2
        pos2 = player1
    }

    for _ in 0...9 {
        pos1.cardDealt(deck.getNextCard())
        pos2.cardDealt(deck.getNextCard())
    }
}
```

A more compact way to do this would be to swap the values using tuples and the ternary operator:

```
   func dealCards() {

    // Dealer is considered position 2
    let (pos1, pos2) = player1.isDealer() ? (player2, player1) : (player1, player2)
    //If player1 is the dealer, swap pos1 and pos2
    for _ in 0...9 {
        pos1.cardDealt(deck.getNextCard())
        pos2.cardDealt(deck.getNextCard())
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1658921 You're welcome :) Just fyi, I updated my first option so that it is more compact and simpler to understand too, eliminating the need for the `else` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Put your players into an array, and make a loop wrap around, like this:

```
let players = [player1, player2, player3, ...] 
var startFrom = 0 // Set to 1 to start from player2, 2 to start from player3, etc.
for _ in 0...9 {
    for i in 0..<players.count {
        players[(startFrom + i) % players.count].cardDealt(deck.getNextCard())
    }
}
```

Variable `startFrom` contains the index of the first player to receive a card. Playerd receive their cards in the same order, wrapping around at `players.count` position.